# How to apply rgba gradient in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-color

I am getting values in following format from designer to draw a gradient.

```
rgba(90, 111, 101, 0.22);
```

I need to apply this to a view, what i know so far, is that, I can define gradient like following.

```
<gradient
    android:startColor="#2ea4e7"
    android:centerColor="#015664"
    android:endColor="#636969"
    android:angle="45"
    >

</gradient>
```

But i am unable to understand how to map that rgba gradient in android.

Answer (score 0):

A gradient requires at least a start and an end color. Your designer has provided you with one color with transparency (alpha).
To convert this color into hexadecimal format, you can use:

```
String hex = String.format("#%02X%02X%02X", r, g, b);
```

and concatenate the transparency by converting the transparency percentage from 0 to 255 (i.e. FF) into hex.

For example, 22% of 255 is 56, so 38 in hex.

Therefore the given color in hexadecimal format is `#5A6F6538`